# Bootstrap columns to same height AND child to match height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As the title implies, I'm trying to get the uniformity and clean lines that your normal `<table>` offers, but with the responsiveness of Bootstrap Grid System. I've used the **partial solution [found here](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height)**, to get the columns to match each other's height.

**Here's [my layout in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kragalon/aar9wuxc/2/) (roughly)**. Blue border is for the columns to show them at same height.

The thing is, the inner divs are not matching the height. The right section is going to be a chatroom, so the textarea is a fixed height, as well as the header, so I'm trying to get the message area to take up the extra height. I can't seem to get `display:flex` to work there.

I don't mind if the solution is in Javascript or CSS, just as long as it is responsive.

Also, in case you think that I should just set the columns to have the style of the inner `divs` and add a margin to them, it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!