# Bootstrap well same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the bootstrap class [well](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells) for decoration. I have two divs with different amount of entries inside. Is it possible that both wells fill their parent and have always the same height no matter how many entries they contain?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <strong>Title</strong>
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div>Item 1</div>
                <div>Item 2</div>
                <div>Item 3</div>
                <div>Item 4</div>
                <div>Item 5</div>
                <div>Item 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <strong>Title</strong>
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div>Item 1</div>
                <div>Item 2</div>
                <div>Item 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried different solutions but didn’t succeed. I want to avoid the flex box layout because of its weak support. If I use tables instead of bootstrap columns I get the same result. How can I handle this with CSS (and possibly without adding JavaScript) ?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malio/jm0zkzx8/)

Comment: i have a solution but with jQuery only without css.

Comment: I could also use jQuery.

Comment: ya and css you have to use flex

Comment: How would you solve it with jQuery?

Comment: nothing just check each row and find the max height then set it on .well class. I dn't answer yet because you mention possibly with out javascript. 
but without jQuery you have to use display flex.

Comment: place my answer with full code. take a look. just add the border for make sure height is same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap columns to same height AND child to match height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571190/bootstrap-columns-to-same-height-and-child-to-match-height)

Comment: @Patrick to my knowledge **there's no way to dynamically find out which element is the tallest** and apply that height to the rest of the group **in CSS**. If you can use some **`JavaScript/jQuery`**, then you can find a couple of good solution in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39552118/6313073).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**JavaScript:**

If you are okay with using a little bit of JavaScript then the following will be exactly what you need:

```
var
  elements = document.querySelectorAll(".well"),
  heights = [];

/* Getting an array with the heights */
[].forEach.call(elements, function(each) {
  heights[heights.length] = getComputedStyle(each, null).getPropertyValue("height");
});

/* Sorting the array to get the greatest value first */
heights.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a);
});

/* Applying the greatest height to each element */
[].forEach.call(elements, function(each) {
  each.style.height = heights[0];
});
```

---

**jQuery:**

If instead you're in for shorter code and you use **`jQuery`** you can use the following code:

```
var max;

/* Getting the greatest height */
$(".well").each(function() {
  max = ($(this).height() > max) ? $(this).height() : max;
});

/* Applying the greatest height to each element */
$(".well").height(max);
```

---

**Execution times:**

1. JavaScript: **`0.562ms`**
2. jQuery: **`2.889ms`** *(~5x slower)*

---

Here's a **snippet** demonstrating the solution:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var
  elements = document.querySelectorAll(".well"),
  heights = [];

[].forEach.call(elements, function(each) {
  heights[heights.length] = getComputedStyle(each, null).getPropertyValue("height");
});

heights.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a);
});

[].forEach.call(elements, function(each) {
  each.style.height = heights[0];
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
.well {
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <strong>Title</strong>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
        <div>Item 5</div>
        <div>Item 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <strong>Title</strong>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don´t know why but in firefox and chrome this code seems to work fine but in internet explorer not. Maybe someone has an idea ?

Comment: IE version 11 x64

Answer (score 7):

**I use this solution for that problem**

Without JavaScript.

I found it on [**this link**](http://www.bootply.com/126437#).

```
<div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
    //Your well code
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

and add this css:

```
.row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

.row-flex-wrap {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex:0;
}

.row-flex > div[class*='col-'], .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
     margin:-.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
}

.container-flex > div[class*='col-'] div,.row-flex > div[class*='col-'] div {
    width:100%;
}


.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1 100%;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.flex-grow {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
}
```

Hope this will helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

You can set another class to the divs if you have the exact height size value you want it to have:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <strong>Title</strong>
      <div class="well well-sm test">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
        <div>Item 5</div>
        <div>Item 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <strong>Title</strong>
      <div class="well well-sm test">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And for example if your max height value is `300px` (or can be min-height):

```
.test {
  height: 300px !important;
}
```

It will be the same size, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldfdu65n/4/)

But! if you want to make it the same height, without having a fixed height value, then I think you'd need to use javascript to get the biggest's divs height.

Take an example here:

[How to set height of element to match height of another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458465/how-to-set-height-of-element-to-match-height-of-another-element)

There's a very quick snippet I made for you using jQuery, it's made pretty badly, i am sure there are better and short ways:

```
var max = 0;
$.each( $('.row > div > div'), function(i, row) {
            var cheight = $(row).height();
            if (cheight > max) {
            max = cheight;
      }
})

$.each( $('.row > div > div'), function(i, row) {
        $(row).height(max);
})
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldfdu65n/5/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t know the max or min size. I think I try to solve it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer with jQuery [https://jsfiddle.net/mjgLufa1/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/mjgLufa1/1/)

```js
var maxHeight = 0;

$(".row").each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
  }
});

$(".well ").height(maxHeight);
```

```css
  .well{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
     }
```

```html
       <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" >  </script>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <strong>Title</strong>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
        <div>Item 5</div>
        <div>Item 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <strong>Title</strong>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `.row-eq-height`.

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
... 
</div>
```

Note this example: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Might be useful in your case.

Comment: I’ve seen this before but unfortunately it is based on flexbox layout. I rather go with a js solution.

Comment: Hm, fine! What about to customize a column instead? Isn't better?